# Scanner as parameter and convert to int? (JAVA)

Tags: java

I have a trouble about usage of the scanner.
The getUserInput takes as an input the scanner instance and initialise the array of specified size which comes from the scanner. For example: if user puts 3 then the method will create an array of the size 3.

However, it keeps saying that scnr can't converted to int....
Any advice?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("How many orders were placed Saturday?");
  int [] userInput = getUserInput(scnr);
  System.out.println("How many orders were placed Sunday?");
  int [] userInput = getUserInput(scnr);
  System.out.println("How many orders were placed Monday?");
  int [] userInput = getUserInput(scnr) 

  return;
 }
}


 public static int[] getUserInput(Scanner scnr)
 {
   int[] userInput = new int[scnr];

   return userInput;   
 }
```

Comment: Do you really want to return an array of integers from getUserInput()?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call a method on `Scanner`. And because you want an int do it like this:

```
int[] userInput = new int[scnr.nextInt()];
```

Here you'll find the API documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0):

`nextInt()`  method of Java Scanner class is used to scan the next token of the input as an int

```
public static int[] getUserInput(Scanner scnr)
     {
       int[] userInput = new int[scnr.nextInt()];
    
       return userInput;   
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there are 2 mistakes you have done here.

1. `int [] userInput` there are 2 duplicates of this userInput variable.
2. You are passing an instance of `Scanner` as a parameter in your `getUserInput` function.

> getUserInput  FIX

So in order to create we need to follow a syntax i.e

```
datatype [] vairable_name = new datatype[size];
```

Here size can be `byte` `short` `int` but what you did is

```
datatype [] vairable_name = new datatype[Scanner];
```

Which is just not the Syntax. You can fix it by taking input as `int` from the user.
A scanner as a method to do that `.nextInt()` which converts the input of the user to int if it's in numbers. 
Solution is

```
int[] userInput = new int[scnr.nextInt()];
// This is like the syntax 
datatype [] vairable_name = new datatype[Scanner];
```

> Duplicate Variable

You should revise scopes in java, and then you will know why it's an error.
You cannot have the same variable name in the same scope or in the child scope

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   int a = 0;
   int a = 1; // <- error because a is already defined and is duplicate in the same scope.
}
```

Similarly

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   int a = 0;
   if(true){
      int a = 1; // <- error because a is already defined and is duplicate in child scope.
   }
}
```

The solution is to change the variable name.

```
//scnr is now globally available in the class so need to pass it as a parameter 
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
  System.out.println("How many orders were placed Saturday?");
  int [] saturdayUserInput = getUserInput();
  System.out.println("How many orders were placed Sunday?");
  int [] sundayUserInput = getUserInput();
  System.out.println("How many orders were placed Monday?");
  int [] mondayUserInput = getUserInput() 

  return;
 }
}

 public static int[] getUserInput()
 {
   int[] userInput = new int[scnr.nextInt()];

   return userInput;   
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

scnr is not an int. It's an isntance of the Scanner class. If you want to read an int from it, you'll need to call:

```
scnr.nextInt();
```

It's also better not to pass this as a parameter, but to create the Scanner on class level, so you can use it in all the methods.